# gdb logging not working

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, logging, gdb

I am trying to debug a program using `gdb`. The problem is that no log file appears. Do I need to exit the `gdb`-session in a specific way or what could be wrong?

Starting `gdb` and showing logging settings gives this:

```
gdb python3
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.5) 7.11.1
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from python3...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) show logging
Future logs will be written to gdb.txt.
Logs will be appended to the log file.
Output will be logged and displayed.
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is that no log file appears

You did not enable logging, enable it with `set logging on`:

```
(gdb) set logging on
Copying output to gdb.txt.
(gdb) show logging
Currently logging to "gdb.txt".
Logs will be appended to the log file.
Output will be logged and displayed.
```

Comment: Thank you. I just assumed that "Future logs will be written to gdb.txt" meant that would be logged.